# Show that certain matrices over rings form a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I have got the following assignment:

$R$ is a ring, $K:=\{  
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}:  a,b \in R\}$

I need to show that $K$ is a field. And I believe it is not true.

Consider the ring of integers, $a= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
-2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\ne \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ does not have an inverse in $\mathbb Z^{2 \times 2}$ and consequently in $K$. Indeed, if the inverse existed, then $\det(a)=5$ would have an inverse element in $\mathbb Z$. So $K$ can not be a field.

Is my logic correct or I am misunderstanding the assignment?

Comment: Yes, you're correct; the claim is true only for some rings (most importantly, $\Bbb R$, in which case $K \cong \Bbb C$).

Comment: Certainly $R=\mathbb R$ and you missed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when $R$ is just a (commutative) ring, what you can say is that $K$ is a subring of $M_2(R)$.

*If* the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible in $K$, it is invertible in $M_2(R)$, so its determinant must be invertible in $R$. Conversely, if the determinant $a^2+b^2$ is invertible in $R$, the inverse belongs to $K$, as it is easy to show.

This shows that $K$ is a field if and only if $a$ and $b$ not both zero implies $a^2+b^2$ invertible in $R$.

In the case where $R$ is the real field, $K$ *is* indeed a field.